# HP ALM 12.5 - How to Make Test Sets Read Only in Test Lab Module

Tags: alm, hp-quality-center, hp-alm

I am trying to make particular test set Read Only, meaning no one will be able to run, delete or modify these particular test set.

I also don't know how to make Test Sets and also Folders Read Only for Delete and Modify functions yet, any help there I will be thankful too):

In Test Lab module Script --> TestSet_MoveTo Sub:

```
If TestSet_Fields.Field("TC_Cycle_ID").Value = 103 Then
   Actions.Action("TestSetView.Run").Enabled = FALSE
   Actions.Action("TestSetView.RunTestSet").Enabled = FALSE

Else
  Actions.Action("TestSetView.Run").Enabled = TRUE
  Actions.Action("TestSetView.RunTestSet").Enabled = TRUE

End If
```

Now it disables "Run" button for **all test sets** in Test Lab in addition to Test Set with Test Set ID 103. I'm not sure if I'm doing anything wrong in coding above. This should have only disabled the Run and RunTestSet buttons for Test Set ID 103.

Also, even when test sets show disabled Run button (for all test sets), the Status of a test set can be changed through Execution Grid. How can I disable this field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `CY_CYCLE_ID` and not the `TC_Cycle_ID` field.

```
If TestSet_Fields.Field("CY_CYCLE_ID").Value = "103" then
   ....
End If
```

As you can see, the `CY_CYCLE_ID` field represents the testset ID:

[image]