# HPQC ALM - How to make TC_PLAN_SCHEDULING_DATE Read Only

Tags: alm, hp-quality-center, hp-alm

I am trying to make "Planned Exec Date" field read only inTest Lab --> Execution Grid.

In Test Lab Module script --> TesSetTests_FieldCanChange Sub, I have added the following code:

```
TestSetTest_Fields.Field("TC_PLAN_SCHEDULING_DATE").IsReadOnly = True
```

But still date can be changed and added by writing in the field or choosing from calendar.

How do I make this field read only?

Thanks.

Sohel

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43009917/hp-alm-12-5-how-to-make-test-sets-read-only-in-test-lab-module Have you checked this other thread? I guess it should be similar to what you asked last time. Maybe a different value to be used. :-)

Comment: Thanks Marco, I resolved the problem but didn't update this post, will do so now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the problem by putting the code into TestSetTests_MoveTo sub.

```
Sub TestSetTests_MoveTo
  On Error Resume Next
  TestSetTest_Fields.Field("TC_PLAN_SCHEDULING_DATE").IsReadOnly = True
End Sub
```